# Does the AWS Amplify withAuthenticator React HOC have to wrap the root node? Can Auth be optional?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, aws-amplify

I'd like to give users the option to create accounts and login but I don't want to force them to create an account to use the site I'm building. Is this possible with the Amplify React `withAuthenticator` HOC?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. Only wrap the authentication related pages / components with `withAuthenticator` that way it only shows up when you navigate to those pages (assuming you're code-splitting pages). You can then probably associate the page to the corresponding authentication view by changing the configuration but I think a better way might be to just use the authenticator components like `<Authenticator authState="signUp" />`